# Spinning an image using rotateY

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'd like to spin an image and I came across this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nD8xqlh6Esk which gave a very simple way to spin a div on a click. I thought this would be a great method to spin an image on a page load with minimal css so tried using a :after as opposed to a :click (with 720 deg) but that didn't work. Has anyone got this approach to work on a page load rather than on a click? I've seen other methods but they need quite a bit more css.

**Detail provided**

[Apparently my youtube link is to a football match although for me it's to a LevelUp Tuts CSS Experiments #1 - Card Flipping Effect video.]

Basically, he flips a card through a simple transform on a hover as follows:

```
<div class="card"></div>

.card {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY (90deg);
}
```

So you can spin the div with a single line, a transform, on a hover. There's no need for keyframes.

Comment: What didn't work? Show us what you did.

Comment: Here's a very simple jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AB277/89/ . Change the :after to :hover and it'll work.

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo **element**. `:hover` is a state. They're very very different. Actually `:after` is `::after` these days, to differentiate.

Comment: I realise but I was trying to trigger the spin on the page load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: spin 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes spin{
  to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin{
to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

**EDIT:** is this more like what you wanted?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: spin 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes spin{
  to{
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin{
to{
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
}
```

```html
<div id="d"><img src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120208185721/logopedia/images/5/54/Barclays_Premier_League_logo_(shield).gif" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
```

Comment: But that only works when I click on the element. I want the spin to happen when the page loads without clicking on it.

Comment: @PedroKTFC it now spins on load without javascript

Comment: Except in Chrome! :o) But nice.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox but not in Chrome, odd!

Comment: @PedroKTFC just noticed the absence of the webkit prefix, check now, it should work fine

Comment: It's a shame you can't do it with the way I tried so I accepted this as the answer although some of the others were very similar, so sorry to you. I uses Sass and Compass so, for anyone who's interested, I've ended up with the following in my file:    }
.card {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
 \@include animation (sspin 5s linear infinite);
}
@include keyframes (sspin) {
    to { \@include transform (rotateY(360deg)); }
}
(The \ character to "escape" the ats.)

Comment: No worries, I've added the detail to my question. Bizarre you see a football match, just hope the action was good! :) But your answer was good for me.

Comment: By the way, I have used keyframes because transitions require a property to change after load

Answer (score 1):

You need `animation` <s>as well, not just `transition`</s>:

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/AB277/95/

The magic:

```css
.card {
    animation: spinn 5s linear infinite;
    /* you don't need transition at all */
}

@keyframes spinn {
    0%   { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(720deg); }
}
```

For some reason, Chrome still needs prefixes.

[More info on css-tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

Comment: actually, transition isn't required at all, have a look at my answer

Comment: Yeah, I noticed too, when I didn't have any transitions left =) Silly me

Comment: I didn't really check your code, just the word "transition" was enough

Answer (score 1):

this animates the object as soon as the css and the html load:

(http://jsfiddle.net/oemtt7cr/)

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(720deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotateY(720deg);
      }
    }
    .container {
      -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
    }
    .card {
      margin: 20px;
      background: #990;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      animation: spin 5s ease;
      -webkit-animation: spin 5s ease;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">flipy</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.card:hover` instead of `.card:after` if you like the animation start when user move in with cursor.

http://jsfiddle.net/AB277/90/

```
   .card {margin 20px;
        background: blue;
        width: 200px;
        height:200px;
        transition: all 5s;
    }
    .card:hover {
        transform: rotateY(720deg);

    }
```

Or if you like the animation at page load, use the following script.

http://jsfiddle.net/AB277/93/

```
<div id="card"
</div>

var elm = document.getElementById('card');
elm.classList.add('cardMove');


#card {margin 20px;
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    transition: all 5s;
}
.cardMove {
    transform: rotateY(720deg);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to do it without javascript.